# Rails - many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My education app uses single database and has got many users. I have following problem:

When `user1` finishes a lesson (lesson model has a column finished with boolean), this lesson is finished (`finished = true`) for all other users.

I would like this lesson was finished for user1 but unfinished for all other users.

In other words, how can I separate changes in database done by `user1` from changes done by `user2`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one you may use joining table called for example `users_lesson_progresses` with `has_many :through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

See the docs here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

The idea is in `users_lesson_progresses` table you'll have a separate row for every pair of user and lesson. And after a user finishes a lesson, you create a row for this particular user and this particular lesson and set `completed` column value to true. Or after a user starts a lesson you set `state` column in `users_lesson_progresses` table to `started` and after he finishes, you set that column value to `finished`. Same for any other user and any other lesson. That's an examples. Your approach may vary but the main idea is the same.

Comment: Hi VAD, I followed your tip and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you